# Pandas True False Matching

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean, calculated-columns

For this table:

[image]

I would like to generate the 'desired_output' column. One way to achieve this maybe:

1. All the True values from col_1 are transferred straight across to desired_output (red arrow)
2. In desired_output, place a True value above any existing True value (green arrow)

Code I have tried:

```
df['desired_output']=df.col_1.apply(lambda x: True if x.shift()==True else False)
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain by `|` for bitwise `OR` original with shifted values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
d = {"col1":[False,True,True,True,False,True,False,False,True,False,False,False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['new'] = df.col1 | df.col1.shift(-1)
print (df)
     col1    new
0   False   True
1    True   True
2    True   True
3    True   True
4   False   True
5    True   True
6   False  False
7   False   True
8    True   True
9   False  False
10  False  False
11  False  False
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
df['desired_output'] = df['col_1']
df.loc[1:, 'desired_output'] = df.col_1[1:].values | df.col_1[:-1].values
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case those are saved as string. all_caps (TRUE / FALSE)
Input:

```
   col_1
0   True
1   True
2   False
3   True
4   True
5   False
6   Flase
7   True
8   False
```

Code:

```
df['desired']=df['col_1']
for i, e in enumerate(df['col_1']):
    if e=='True':
        df.at[i-1,'desired']=df.at[i,'col_1']
df = df[:(len(df)-1)]
df
```

Output:

```
   col_1    desired
0   True    True
1   True    True
2   False   True
3   True    True
4   True    True
5   False   False
6   Flase   True
7   True    True
8   False   False
```

Comment: @AngusStevenson My answer will specially work if the values are saved as string. "TRUE"(similar to your image in the question), not "True".